# Can't capture via invoice. Gateway error: Credit card number is required. (Authorize.net)

Tags: magento-enterprise, database

We had to restore our database from a backup. I export all the sales tables and imported them into the restored database so we didn't lose orders. Yet now I have a problem where when I try to invoice and capture a sale it gives me the error: Gateway error: Credit card number is required.

I can see in the order that the card has a transaction #. I called Authorize and they said all they need is the transaction # and the amount being charged. I looked in app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php and I validated that the request is AUTH_CAPTURE.

If anyone can suggest where in the database I should look for issues to resolve this problem, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally tracked down the issue. Our Invoice numbers were out of sync. So our system was trying to invoice and capture the wrong order. When I fixed the invoice numbers in the table eav_entity_store it solved the issue.

Comment: I have the same issue. But when I searched in eav_entity_Store,  it is empty. Is there any other solution?